# appjs openDialog return value is garbled

Tags: appjs

using appjs-0.0.20-win32-ia32

```
window.frame.openDialog({
            type: 'save', 
            title: 'Save...', 
            multiSelect: false, 
            dirSelect:true           
            }, function( err , files ) {
               for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
                  console.log(files[i]);
               }

           });
```

example: 轠ѓ轤ѓ轤ѓlo

This issue happens only in Windows 7 with dirSelect true, Its working correct in Ubuntu 12.04.
Also this is working correct if I used the openDialog dirSelect false mode, that is file selection enabled. 
I tried both 64 bit and 32 bit machines.

Comment: Indead this is a bug in I guess [CEF1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appjs-dev/hLeTacsUgU4)... Related: [#354](https://github.com/appjs/appjs/issues/354) and [#254](https://github.com/appjs/appjs/issues/254)

Comment: I searched the source code, I am not an expert in c++, the error should from the below code.
source->native_window->native_window_win.cpp


this is the function I think :
`void NativeWindow::OpenFileDialog(uv_work_t* req)

if (dirSelect) {.......
.......
}`

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. btw here's a link to that file - https://github.com/appjs/appjs/blob/master/src/native_window/native_window_win.cpp